# Debugging Remote Connection Failure of SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows-server

I am running SQL server 2012 web edition on Windows Server 2008 R2. I have followed all these steps http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/. But still unable to connect remotely. How to debug and find why it is not working. Tried everything from all posts. I am getting this error,

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to 
SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance 
name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

When I ran netstat -ano | find /i "3400", where 3400 is my sql process id, I get,

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3400
  TCP    127.0.0.1:56338        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3400
  TCP    [::]:1433              [::]:0                 LISTENING       3400
  TCP    [::1]:56338            [::]:0                 LISTENING       3400
```

Comment: Run `netstat -n -b -p tcp` and see if the SQL Server Express process is listening on tcp port 1433 ?

Comment: @Andomar Thanks. it shows me `Displays protocol statistics and current TCP/IP network connections.` nothing else

Comment: Which connection string are you using?  Try one like `Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`

Comment: Thanks @Andomar I got the issue. I need a restart due to port exhaust.

Comment: @Andomar, if the initial TCP connection fails, the SQL Server client reverts to named pipes (which also failed here).

Answer (score 2):

You've already checked that an instance of SQL Server is running and listening on TCP port 1433.
Check if the SQL Server Browser Service is running:

```
sc query sqlbrowser | find /I "STATE"
```

If it's not, set it to start automatically and try starting it:

```
sc config sqlbrowser start= auto
sc start sqlbrowser
```

Check that it's listening on UDP port 1434:

```
netstat -aon | find ":1434"
```

If all this checks out, and you still can't connect, I'd say verify your firewall settings. Whether built in Windows firewall or otherwise. If permissible, try turning it off completely just for testing, then tweak the rules and reenable it if it works then.
You can also try using psping to verify connectivity to the TCP port. You can download it here, as part of PSTools:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/jj729731.aspx

```
psping 0.0.0.0:1433
```

Replace 0.0.0.0 with the IP or DNS name of your SQL Server host, add -4 or -6 to force IPv4/IPv6 respectively.